Short story, Reston bike paths, dead mom, WHFS
Looking for a short story about WHFS radio station ("the weasel"), Reston bike paths, 1980s, dead mom, etc.
I think it was from the mid 2000s and may have been in Sci Fiction webzine (the thing Ellen Datlow edited).
The author was a minor SF writer, newish, but known.  C. early 60s birth date.  Went to Herndon High School.  I corresponded with him via Internet forum comments.  Maybe SciFiction had comments below the stories or a forum or maybe it was in Nightshade or some general SF forum.
The science fictional element was some sort of time link through the radio.  (I might be mixing up the story "Jeffty is Five" or the movie Frequency with it...but something to that effect.)

[Edit... can't answer as it is closed!]
I figured it out.  It is "Left of the Dial", by Paul Witcover.

What science fiction or fantasy elements does the work contain?

I can't remember it all, but it was sort of like memories from the past from the radio?

When and where did you read this?  When did you correspond with the author?  Was it IMs, tweets, e-mail, snail mail...?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy.

IT was definitely genre.  That's part of what I remember about it.  May have been a bit of a tone piece within that.  But commercially identified as SF.  Open up!

This has been re-opened so you can post the answer now.

WHFS!  That takes me back.

@guestisatroll: Feel free to copy my answer and let me know so that I can delete it.

Welcome back, @guestisatroll! I do hope that you stick around.

Just providing a placeholder answer until/when the original querent returns to post their self answer.
"Left of the Dial" by Paul Witcover features a young man involved in a geeky love triangle in his youth and dealing with the death of his mother, who finds a way to access past broadcasts of WHFS, a local radio station, and thereby to go to the past to confront his mistakes, with the help of his friends, and change his future, whether for the better or for the worse.
It can be read here, also linked from the author's website.
